# Are there any faster browsers than midori or chromium?

Tags: web-browsers, chromium, midori

I just got my first raspberry pi to play with and am working on switching between visible images with JavaScript. My problem is it takes between 6 to 10 seconds from when I click my button for the image to switch on my pi, but it's instant on my mac and windows machine. 
The browser is not retrieving the images from the web each time I press the button. Is there anyway I can make this faster without resizing the images?

Here's the link to my test page: http://ec2-54-211-152-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com/test/test.html

Answer (score 2):

The foundation has been working on an [accelerated browser](http://www.raspberrypi.org/web-browser-beta/) which may work better. The goals they've stated are to improve rendering speed which may help.

Unfortunately the limit you're hitting with display probably isn't so much a browser issue as a more fundamental issue with the frame buffer being slow to update. There's not much you can do about that other than maybe move to OpenGL ES, but if you're working on JavaScript that's probably not the right solution.